# Adding a background image under a background color function

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

I have the three functions running on my interactive pet (change background, dimmer lights, mouse follow). I'm trying to add an image to the background of the body, but every time I try it gets pushed to the top and the dirty/clean tank function doesn't work. Could someone tell me how to change the color sections of the first function below to switch between images instead of color codes? I think that would solve the immediate problem. :/

CSS Code:

```
//change background color: dirty/clean tank
setTimeout(function dirty() { //sets background color to murky green
document.body.style.backgroundColor = ****"#CCCC99";** //would like this to be an image**
var btn = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Clean the tank!"));
    document.body.style.marginTop = "-1000px";

btn.onclick = function clean() {
    btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = **"#CCFFFF";//would like this to be an image**
    setTimeout(dirty,27000); //how long it takes to make the tank dirty
};
},500); //first loading of clear blue timeout


//dim the lights
 var dimmed = 0;
function toggleLights()
{ 
var dimmer = document.getElementById("dimmer");
if(dimmed == 0) dimmed = 1;
else dimmed = 0;

if(dimmed == 1)
{
    dimmer.style.opacity = 0.8;
    dimmer.style.visibility = "visible";
}

if(dimmed == 0)
{
    dimmer.style.opacity = 0.0;
    dimmer.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
}


//fish moves on mouse hover
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#swim").mousemove(function (event) {
var fish = $("#fish1");
var position = fish.position();
var mousey = event.pageX;


if (position.left > mousey) {
    $("#fish1").html("<img src='images/happy.png' />");
} else {
    $("#fish1").html("<img src='images/happyback.png'/>");
}

$("#fish1").stop().animate({
    left: event.pageX,
    top: event.pageY
}, 300);
});
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Untitled</TITLE>


<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pet.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script> 

 </HEAD>



<div id="table">
<div id="dimmer" onClick="toggleLights()"></div>
<a href="javascript:toggleLights();"><img src="images/table-lamp.png" height="380px" 
alt="table lamp"></a>
</div>


<div id="swim">
<div id="fish1"><img src="images/happy.png"/></div>
</div> 

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a starting `<body>` tag in your HTML, and change element classes with javascript, instead of style properties. That way you have more control over the styling through your CSS file.

So you would do something like:

```
document.body.className = 'state1';
```

And in your CSS

```
.state1{
   background-image: url(the/image.jpg);
}
```

and so on...